# Ввод команды в консоль браузера

Tags: браузер

Суть в том, что есть команда `document.body.contentEditable = true`, которая при вводе в консоль браузера позволяет в режиме реального времени редактировать текстовое содержимое на странице. Есть ли способ быстрого ввода в консоль браузера команды? При идеальном раскладе, в котором есть такая возможность, хочу реализовать на подобии кнопки на сайте, чтобы при нажатии само вводило команду в консоль. На самом деле подойдёт любой способ ввода, то расширение для браузера, либо скрипт, написанный на языке.

Comment: браузер хоть укажите

Comment: Если сайт ваш, то добавьте эту команду в код. Либо, в браузере открывайте окно инспектора / инструменты разработчика (попробуйте F12) и там вводите код. Либо найдите расширение для вашего браузера, позволяющее выполнять пользовательские скрипты, например, гугление показало Tampermonkey. Либо сделайте расширение

Comment: @gil9red, `Если сайт ваш, то добавьте эту команду в код.`  В этом и суть вопроса. Какой код?

Comment: @SomeBodyLite, вы не знаете как работать с HTML? В HTML создаете тег `<script>` в него помещаете код на `javascript`, т.к. ваша команда `document.body.contentEditable = true` и есть код на `javascript`

Comment: @gil9red, для того и задавался вопрос, ибо я не знаю как такое сделать.......